# Using Pytorch in AWS lambda Error- "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'torch._C'",

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pytorch, cloud

I am trying to use pytorch in AWS lambda but I keep getting this error.
I am using `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:934676248949:layer:pytorchv1-py36:2` as the layer for pytorch
and this is my handler function

```
import unzip_requirements
import torch



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    return "Hello"
```

As in the function I am just only importing torch and it is giving me this error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'torch._C'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Comment: Not directly related, but might help in your use case: [torchlambda](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/torchlambda) (disclaimer: I'm the author). Approach above wasn't probably maiantained for a long time.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I would love to know.

Comment: Please were you able to sort this out!!? I'm sort of stuck on this for almost a week. @shivkhaira

Comment: facing a similar issue https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/1220 any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your AWS Lambda runtime and your container (when using a layer) or your EC2 instance (when installing on EFS from EC2) use the same Python version.
PyTorch C extensions are compiled for a specific Python version and discrepancies will result in the error you got.

Comment: facing an issue which seems similar https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/1220. @Jean-Baptiste any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

try:
import unzip_requirements
except ImportError:
pass

try this it passes through the ._C dependency

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).